# jQuery on called twice when used with not selector

Tags: jquery

I'm using the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler to register to the register to the 'body' element and fire an event whenever an element which is not in a specific div.
Therefor I'm using the not selector to filter out all those elements. However if I click the element, the event is fired twice, instead of once.

Am I misunderstanding the not selector?

Fiddle sample: http://fiddle.jshell.net/kHbH9/

Sample code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('body').on('click', ':not(#toolbar)', function(){
                    $('body').append('clicked<br/>')
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id"toolbar">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
        <h1>Click here</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem with your markup: `<div id="toolbar">`

Comment: Haha, thanks... now it isn't called twice. however the click still isn't ignored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is `id"toolbar"` which should be `id="toolbar"`. You can use `stopPrapagation` method which prevents the event from bubbling.

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', function() {
         $('body').append('clicked<br/>')
    });
    $('#toolbar').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
    })
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/PHkbR/

Comment: @Stefan I suspect this one is more efficient, because complicated jQuery selectors are notoriously slow. The reason I used `:not` was to explain what was missing in your approach.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you need is:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', ':not(#toolbar, #toolbar *)', function(){
        $('body').append('clicked'+this.nodeName+"<br/>");
    });
});
```

The problem is that the handler is not triggered on the toolbar element, but *is* triggered on all its children (ie the paragraph). You need to exclude all descendants in the selector, which can be accomplished by adding a selector for descendants to the `:not` clause.

If you fix this, along with the markup error I mentioned earlier, it should work fine.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/kHbH9/2/

Comment: nice, I have to select all nested alements too, with '#toolbar *'... thanks. But both versions seem to work, which one is better?